# Discord.py buttton responses "this interaction failed" after a certain time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a slash command that when used it returns a message with a button

after like some times it respond "This Interaction Failed"

is there any way i could fix this issue?

my button code

```py
class Menu(discord.ui.View):

  def __init__(self):

    super().__init__(timeout=None)

    self.value = None

  @discord.ui.button(label="Script", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")

  async def script(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):

    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello world", ephemeral=True)
```

and this is my code for the slash command

```py
@client.tree.command(name="test", description="this is test for button")

async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):

  if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:

   return await interaction.response.send_message("You are not admin")

  else:

    view = Menu()

    embed = discord.Embed(title="test", color=0xfed9ff)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view)
```

i tried fixing it by doing

`view = Menu(timeout=None)`

but just returned an error

i tried fixing it using

`view = Menu(timeout=None)`

but it just returned an error

Answer (score 0):

The timeout should help.

Anyways here is a simple example which works even after a bot restart:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Test",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="my_custom_button")
    async def testbutton(self,interaction:discord.Interaction,button:discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Testing...")

@bot.tree.command(name='testbutton')
async def testbutton(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=MyView())
```

For it to work after the bot restarted, you need to put this line into your `on_ready()` event or create a command where you can put it: `bot.add_view(MyView())`

Comment: I've managed to fix it by making the button dynamic, thanks anyways